# In Apache NiFi, can I evaluate expression language without an attribute?

Tags: apache-nifi

For instance, in a custom processor I may wish to evaluate simply the expression in the String "${UUID()}" (just as an example).

I don't want to expose an attribute to the user, I just want to evaluate the expression. Can I do that?

Comment: Generally the point of expression language is to let the user specify a dynamic expression, or reference incoming flow file attributes. If you weren't going to expose a property to a user, then why would you need EL? Couldn't you just write the code to do whatever was in the expression?

Comment: The code relies on properties (e.g. local LDAP server address) which NiFi reads from files on disk for me, but I don't usually want to expose them to a user, because the LDAP server address isn't going to change.

Comment: I see, when you say "reads from files on disk" are you referring to NiFi's file-based variable registry? or are you reading in a properties file yourself in your processor code?

Comment: Yes, the variable registry.

Comment: Ok then seems like the answer below will work, using something like context.newPropertyValue(expression) and then calling evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue() on the PropertyValue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in a custom processor (or script processor)

```
import org.apache.nifi.components.PropertyValue;
...
String expression = "${UUID()}";
PropertyValue myValue = context.newPropertyValue( expression );
```

in this case it's enough to call this to evaluate expression because no dependency on other attributes in expression itself:

```
String result = myValue.evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue();
```

but if you use attributes in expression:

```
Map<String, String> attributes = ...;
String result = myValue.evaluateAttributeExpressions(attributes).getValue();
```

or if all required attributes in a flowfile:

```
String result = myValue.evaluateAttributeExpressions(flowFile).getValue();
```